# Creating a Key object from byte array in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, encoding, cryptography, key

I have an EC KeyPair generated like so:

```
 KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
 kpg.initialize(256);
 KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Due to some issues, i need to send a key from this keypair as a byte array.

The way i obtain the byte array is just by calling:

```
val keyBytes = kp.public.encoded
```

**My goal is to rebuild this exact key using this byte array.**

I tried:

```
val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
val pkSpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
val publicKey = kf.generatePublic(pkSpec)
```

My issue is that the publicKey.encoded byte array turns out different from the keyBytes array. This makes no sense. I assume this is because of this line:

```
val pkSpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
```

But i haven't been able to find any good info on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use KeyFactory to create the Keys from your byte arrays, check bellow example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.KeyFactory;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // Generate Keys
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        kpg.initialize(256);
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();              

        // The other side
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC"); 
        PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded()));
        PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey.getEncoded()));
       
        // Validation
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(publicKey2.getEncoded(), publicKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(privateKey2.getEncoded(), privateKey.getEncoded()));
    }
}
```